# Why is Where method with forEach faster than forEach by itself

Tags: c#

So I have those 2 codes. and the first one is roughly 1/3 faster than the 2nd one.

From my understanding `Where()` method is applying the condition on each element of the list. Therefore it does 2 checks inside Where (for each item), then runs a ForEach loop on filtered list and does exactly the same checks for each of those items.
So if my list had 100 items and the filtered list is 50 items, it would do

(2 checks for 100 items) + (2 if checks for 50 items) = 300 checks

```
notes.Where(n => n.cBy == 0 || n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue).ToList().ForEach(n =>
    {
        if (n.cBy == 0)
            n.cBy = context.UserContext.id;
        if (n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
            n.cDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    });
```

as opposed to this one:
(2 if checks for 100 items) = 200 checks

```
notes.ForEach(n =>
    {
        if (n.cBy == 0)
            n.cBy = context.UserContext.id;
        if (n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
            n.cDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    });
```

cheers

Comment: "Therefore it does 2 checks inside Where" Not when the first condition already passes. Anyway: how did you check the performance? You would need a benchmark-test with millions of elements to make any valid statement, not just a few hundreds.

Comment: Also, have you even tried to compare the speed of `notes.Where(...).ToList()` and `notes.ToList()`? As TheGeneral said, it very well could be that retrieving 50 rows from database is faster than retrieving 100 rows, and that difference could make the `ForEach` execution time irrelevant

Comment: What is `notes` in this question? it matters. Also, frankly `ForEach` is a bad idea in the first place - a regular `foreach` is virtually always *much* faster than `ForEach`.

Comment: If `notes` is an Enitity Framework (core) DbSet, `Where` will be run as part as the SQL command, which is much faster than in-memory.

Comment: The second `ForEach` strongly suggests that `notes` is a `List<T>`. Is that right @TomaszGolinski?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half the trick in anything like this is making good measurements; here's how you would do it with `BenchmarkDotNet`, if we assume that `notes` is a `List<T>` (to get `ForEach`) - results first, then code; the point is - it isn't obvious that it behaves as you say:

```
|       Method |  Job | Runtime |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------- |----- |-------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|        First |  Clr |     Clr | 1,020.6 ns | 1.5494 ns | 1.3735 ns | 0.0305 |     - |     - |     201 B |
|       Second |  Clr |     Clr |   769.6 ns | 3.3085 ns | 3.0948 ns | 0.0134 |     - |     - |      88 B |
| BasicForEach |  Clr |     Clr |   768.1 ns | 1.7016 ns | 1.5917 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|        First | Core |    Core |   698.3 ns | 5.1906 ns | 4.8553 ns | 0.0229 |     - |     - |     192 B |
|       Second | Core |    Core |   637.4 ns | 0.4207 ns | 0.3935 ns | 0.0105 |     - |     - |      88 B |
| BasicForEach | Core |    Core |   711.7 ns | 2.9788 ns | 2.7864 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
```

It goes without saying that the more realistic you can make the data in the `Setup()` method, the more useful the test will be. But this gives a broad indication that there isn't an *inherent* trend.

---

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main() => BenchmarkDotNet.Running.BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyBenchmarks>();
}

[CoreJob, ClrJob, MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MyBenchmarks
{
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _notes = new List<Foo>(100);
        var rand = new Random(12345);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _notes.Add(new Foo
            {
                cDate = rand.Next(10) <= 5 ? DateTimeOffset.MinValue : DateTime.Now,
                cBy = rand.Next(3),
            });
        }
        _context = new Context
        {
            UserContext = new UserContext
            {
                id = 42
            }
        };
    }
    private Context _context;
    private List<Foo> _notes;
    class Context
    {
        public UserContext UserContext { get; set; }
    }
    class UserContext
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void First()
    {
        var notes = _notes;
        var context = _context;
        notes.Where(n => n.cBy == 0 || n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue).ToList().ForEach(n =>
        {
            if (n.cBy == 0)
                n.cBy = context.UserContext.id;
            if (n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
                n.cDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        });
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Second()
    {
        var notes = _notes;
        var context = _context;
        notes.ForEach(n =>
        {
            if (n.cBy == 0)
                n.cBy = context.UserContext.id;
            if (n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
                n.cDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        });
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BasicForEach()
    {
        var notes = _notes;
        var context = _context;
        foreach(var n in notes)
        {
            if (n.cBy == 0)
                n.cBy = context.UserContext.id;
            if (n.cDate == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
                n.cDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }
    }

}

public class Foo
{
    internal int cBy { get; set; }
    internal DateTimeOffset cDate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first foreach can acts on a shorted list than the second.

So the first is faster than the second.

In the first code with Where you have only one test condition with two predicates and next you foreach on the Where result.

In your second code with only a foreach on all items, you have two test with one predicate each, so it is slower because it requires more cpu cycles to parse all items with two `if` than one `if` to reduce the list before your final test.

With the first code, you test items one time to get whose you want before act on desired.

With the second code, you test items two times to act on desired.

Comment: You answer contradicts itself (first saying that the second foreach is faster, then saying otherwise)